# Matching input text and input file to each other in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a dynamic form that allows someone to add a row that has 2 input types. The first one can be an image or text field and the second one is always a text field. I need the first field to be tied with the second field in post. So I can add to a database field1A and field2A in the same row. The issue is that a file upload is in its own array so I can't just loop through my text array and know that the image is tied to that text field.

```
<input type="text" name="field1[]">
```

If I loop through my field1[] array and get the index it will be different than my $_Files and I don't know where in the array my files are.

```
        Field1  |  Field2
    -----------------------
 A      text    |  text
    -----------------------
 B  file upload |  text
    -----------------------
```

Comment: Can you pls add the complete sample code?

Comment: Show us how you add your dynamic fields in the form, and how you tried to process them, for us to better assist you in your task.

Comment: You can name your input fields whatever you want. Add an index to associate the fields together. E.g. `field[0][text]`, `field[0][file]`, `field[1][text]`, `field[1][file]`, etc. If you include more of your code, we can advise how you can change it to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet, like @fubar said would be to set the keys while you are rendering the html :

```
<input type="text" name="field[0][0]">
<input type="file" name="field[1][0]">

<input type="text" name="field[0][1]">
<input type="text" name="field[1][1]">

<input type="text" name="field[0][2]">
<input type="file" name="field[1][2]">
```

Then you could loop in PHP like this :

```
foreach($_POST['field'][0] as $key => $value) {
    $field1 = $_POST['field'][0][$key];
    $field2 = $_POST['field'][1][$key] ?? $_FILE['field'][1][$key];
}
```